# Workflow form display error

Tags: workflow, infopath, tasks, spservices

I am trying to create a workflow that has an approval process. Once i create the workflow and start it. I get a task added in a Task list but when i try to view it i get this error.

> The form cannot be rendered. This may be due to a misconfiguration of the Microsoft SharePoint Server State Service. For more information, contact your server administrator.

So i searched and found out it happens when the "state service" is not started. So i looked and the service as always been active. But i still get the error.

[image: Services]

Is it possible that this error could be generated because i do not have infopath installed ? Am using IE lastest.

Thanks for the help :)

UPDATE: I've delete the State Service and recreated it using the wizard and i still get the same problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed infopath service to be connected to State Service. It will appear as a warning inside the health monitor.